Setting Individual Stop Losses for Pyramid Orders in Pine Script
I'm currently developing a trading strategy in Pine Script on TradingView, and I'm facing a challenge in setting individual stop losses for pyramid orders. Here's the relevant part of my strategy order code:
// Track entry conditions for long trades
if longcolorcond and timeCond
    lastSignalBar := bar_index
    buyPositions += 1
    sl_long := low - 0.000005
    strategy.entry("Long #" + str.tostring(buyPositions), strategy.long, stop=sl_long, qty = qty_long)
    label.new(bar_index,low, text = "Buy # " + str.tostring(buyPositions), color = color.green, style = label.style_label_up, yloc = yloc.belowbar, textcolor = color.white)

// Track exit conditions for long trades
if STdown and buyPositions > 0
    label.new(bar_index,high, text = "TP hit for " + str.tostring(buyPositions) + " Positions", color = color.green, style = label.style_label_down, yloc = yloc.abovebar, textcolor = color.white)    
    strategy.close_all("TP hit for " + str.tostring(buyPositions) + " Positions")
    buyPositions := 0
    sl_long := na

// Track entry conditions for short trades
if shortcolorcond and timeCond
    lastSignalBar := bar_index
    sellPositions += 1
    sl_short := high + 0.000005
    strategy.entry("Short #" + str.tostring(sellPositions), strategy.short, stop=sl_short, qty = qty_short)
    label.new(bar_index,high, text = "Sell # " + str.tostring(sellPositions), color = color.red, style = label.style_label_down, yloc = yloc.abovebar, textcolor = color.white)

// Track exit conditions for short trades
if STup and sellPositions > 0
    label.new(bar_index,high, text = "TP hit for " + str.tostring(sellPositions) + " Positions", color = color.green, style = label.style_label_up, yloc = yloc.belowbar, textcolor = color.white)    
    
    sl_short := na
    strategy.close_all("TP hit for " + str.tostring(sellPositions) + " Positions")
    sellPositions := 0

In this code, I'm using the SuperTrend indicator to trigger closing all positions ("All TP Close") for pyramid orders. However, I need to set individual stop losses for each pyramid order. Specifically, when the SuperTrend is in a trend, I want each pyramid order's stop loss to be set at the low of the signal candle. If any of the positions' stop loss is hit while the SuperTrend is still in a trend, I want only that specific position to be closed, not all positions.
Image Reference:

Could someone please guide me on how to implement this functionality in Pine Script?
I've attempted to implement individual stop losses for pyramid orders in my Pine Script strategy. Specifically, I modified the strategy order code to set stop losses at the low of the signal candle for each pyramid order. I expected that when a stop loss is hit for one position while the SuperTrend is in a trend, only that specific position would be closed, leaving the other positions open. However, what actually resulted is that all positions are closed when any stop loss is hit, regardless of the SuperTrend's trend status or no position was closed on one SL hit but all Positions were closed on Supertrend change.
